# Flash event errors on IIS7+

Tags: actionscript-3, iis-7, iis-7.5

Flash app I've built works fine on desktop and on IIS6, but when I upload to IIS7+ it breaks.
Most of the app appears to work as expected but a crucial test fails. I think it's a custom event that is failing, but I've no idea why when it works perfectly everywhere else.

Anybody else has issues with Flash and IIS7+?

My app is built with Flash CS5 and AS3 for Flash player 10.

BTW it's not a MIME type issue.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Barry

Comment: Can you be more vague on the issue at hand? Post some code. Throw a bone. Something. Chances are since it worked on one server and not the other the issue is NOT your code but something along the lines of a server config issue.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, but at the time I couldn't work out where the issue was. It turns out the issue was the use of '+' character in filenames when loading images, which IIS7 turns into query strings. Trouble was it was failing silently in places, and it was only through inspecting HTTP headers and deliberately inducing errors elsewhere I worked it out.
I would've posted code but it's large AS3 OOP project and I couldn't isolate the problem enough to do so.
Was really casting around for pointers for directions to look in.
Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the '+' character in filenames on servers running IIS7+. IIS7 treats these as if they were query strings. So a filename 'hello+world+today.jpg' will be translated into 'hello.jpg?key=world+today'. This *sometimes* fails silently in Flash without throwing an IOError, assuming you set up to receive one of course.